# Feedback on Assembly answer

Tags: unix, assembly, grep, mips

I have been asked to provide a solution to the following question;

1.A) In MIPS assembly, there are many ways of copying the contents of one register into another register, using only one instruction. Write five single instructions, which each copy the contents of `$s0` into `$s1`. You cannot use MIPS pseudo-instructions.

I have worked out the following solutions, however I am unable to find a way to "mark" them so please reply if there are "easier" ways or if you think any of the following are wrong;

```
add $s1, $s0, $zero
addi $s1, $s0, 0
sub $s1, $s0, $zero
lw $s1, 0($s0)
and $s1, $s0, $zero
```

As a further point I also have the following question, which has completely thrown me, mainly due to the double ^ involved;

1.B) If we execute the following grep command:

```
grep -E "^[^a][bc].*"
```

Which of the following lines (typed on the console) will be matched?

```
abc
AbX
Zc
ZcHello
aBNo
bb
bDbc
bca
cba
bbbbb
```

Any help is of course greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.  Might be best to find the answer logically on your own instead of getting our answer

Comment: It's a question on a past paper that I'm revising with, I have AbX,
Zc, ZcHello, bb, bca, cba, bbbb and would like anothers opinion thats all

Comment: You can check which grep matches yourself! If you're confused about why a specific one matches, you can ask about that here. `echo "linetotest" | grep -E "^[^a][bc].*"`

Comment: Dumping random, unrelated questions with little value for others is definitely not the way to use StackOverflow...

Answer (score 1):

4 out of 5 look fine to me.

However the operation:

```
lw $s1, 0($s0)
```

does not do what you want. The X(REG) syntax does *indirect addressing*. Let's say that $s0 contains 1165. In this case, `lw $s1, 0($s0)` would put into $s1 the value stored at memory address 1165. `lw $s1, 4($s0)` would put the value at memory address 1169 into $s0.

Hopefully that's clear. If not, you can google indirect addressing, or ask, and I'll try to explain it better.

If you want to test out MIPS code, there's an excellent java based MIPS simulator that lets you 'inspect' the state of the cpu, step through your program, etc:

http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/

Unfortunately I'm no grep expert so I can't help you there. As with any UNIX program, take a look at the manpage and help message:

man page:

```
man grep
```

help message:

```
grep --help
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry to reply to this so late, could you give an alternative to `lw $s1, 0($s0)` as I've done some research and cant find one myself. It can use any op, it just cannot involved MIPS pseudo-instructions. Thanks!

Comment: @DanDoughty `andi $s1, $s0, 0` will do it, so will `ori $s1, $s0, 1`, I'm sure there are many more.